# Exoplayer error 403: Unrecognized media format

Tags: android, react-native, video-streaming, exoplayer, m3u8

I try to play video streaming, with some links it works but with the link of my API no.

I have tested the URL and it seems that in video simulators on the web it works correctly, but not on my device

The code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Video fom 'react-native-video';

export default class VideoTest extends React.Component {

render() {
    return (
         <View>
                <Video
                source={{ uri: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/yojma/hls/movie/TDGVYNnBhbQMusqagzXlUZmKxcJPEoSdvIpwLAef/main.m3u8"}}
            />               
         </View>
    )
}}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think that `m3u8` is supported by Android https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats

Comment: That's right, but I'm using exoPlayer that does have support for HLS. In the documentation of react-native-video it also says that it supports it.

The strange occurrence is that with other test links I am playing video. But not with my link!

Comment: Other `m3u8` links work? Could it be an AWS issue? Could your file be corrupt?

Comment: That's right, other links work. It does not seem to be an AWS problem or corrupt file. Because I have tried the file in the web browser and everything works fine. I've tried the url here: https://developer.jwplayer.com/tools/stream-tester/

Answer (score -1):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Video from 'react-native-video';

export default class VideoTest extends React.Component {

render() {
    return (
         <View>
            <Video
                source={{type:'m3u8', uri: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/yojma/hls/movie/TDGVYNnBhbQMusqagzXlUZmKxcJPEoSdvIpwLAef/main.m3u8"}}
            />               
         </View>
    )
}}
```